# Unable to Clean boot disk space

Tags: jdk

I use a sony vaio and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to install Windows 7 and whenever I insert a bootable usb drive, Error occurs. It says that 693 MB of boot disk space require. How to clean boot disk space;rather I have tried du –sh /var/cache/apt/archives and sudo apt-get clean. Nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

What space do you want to clean? On a USB drive? Or you mean you want to free space on your hard drive to install windows there?

For clearing HD space, assuming you have enough free space, I'd run `gparted` (maybe from a live iso/cd/dvd) and shrink partitions until there's enough free space to create a new partition of the desired size, then tell the windows installer to use the new/empty partition.

For clearing a USB drive, it's pretty much the same thing only it should work without needing to run a live usb/cd/iso.